# Regular expression replace all occurrences of any word beginning with a certain substring

Tags: regex, powershell

Working with Windows PowerShell, I am trying to replace all occurrences of a certain word pattern in a big string, by appending a suffix.

```
$string = "The string that contains several occurrences of ab_abcde, ab_abcde_FOO, ab_vwxyz, ab_vwxyz_BAR, etc"
```

I want to append the suffix "_XXX" to each one of these matched words in `$string`

Since I expect all my matches to start with either `ab_abcde` or `ab_vwxyz`, I have tried:

```
$string -replace "(ab_abcde|ab_vwxyz)(.?)\s+", '$1$2_XXX'
```

and a million other variations, to no avail.

I have spent all day hunting at SO, but haven't found a solution that works well. I would appreciate a little assistance.

PS: Since my `$string` is actually the output of mysqldump, some of my search words will be wrapped in between grave-accent(`) like so: `ab_abcde`, and I would like to match them. I am not sure how much complexity this might bring, considering that this is also the PowerShell escape character.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your expected output? Did you want `ab_abcde_FOO` to become `ab_abcde_XXX_FOO` ?

Comment: I want `ab_abcde` to become `ab_abcde_XXX`, while `ab_abcde_FOO` becomes `ab_abcde_FOO_XXX`

Comment: Anonymous downvoter, wouldn't it be better to do it with a comment, so at least I could see your point (and get better)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
$string -replace "((?:ab_abcde|ab_vwxyz)\w*)", '$1_XXX'
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wU8gD0/1)

Comment: Thanks. This works very well indeed. Now, to break it down to bits? The `\w*` portion seems the be where the job was done, right? So, why not `\w+` which I think I had tried?

Comment: Sorry, I was done commenting before I bothered to follow your regex101 link. Its a great resource. Thanks again.

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo You are welcome :) The difference is that`\w+` matches one or more occurence where as `\w*` matches zero or more hence `ab_abcde` would be caught by `\w*` but not by `\w+` since there isnt any characters following `ab_abcde`. Hope its clear for you now

Comment: That's the thing! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
$string = "The string that contains several occurrences of ab_abcde, ab_abcde_FOO, ab_vwxyz, ab_vwxyz_BAR, etc"

$string -replace '(ab_abcde.*?\b|ab_vwxyz.*?\b)', '$1_XXX'

The string that contains several occurrences of ab_abcde_XXX, ab_abcde_FOO_XXX, ab_vwxyz_XXX, ab_vwxyz_BAR_XXX, etc
```

Edit: updated after additional comments posted.

Comment: Thanks @mjolinor, but I want `ab_abcde` to become `ab_abcde_XXX`, while `ab_abcde_FOO` becomes `ab_abcde_FOO_XXX`, etc

Comment: I saw the comments in the question, and updated the answer to accomodate that.

Comment: Thanks. This works also, but since the other answer came in first, and I'd started taking a look at it before yours, I had to mark that one. Thanks again.